# Select records beginning with defined symbol from database

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have this code:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "' AND m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");
```

and database table:

```
manufacturer_id | name | image | sort_order
```

How can I get all records begining with symbol "B" or with "9" in column `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM manufacturer m LEFT JOIN manufacturer_to_store m2s ON m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id 
WHERE m2s.store_id = <some store id here> 
   AND (m.name LIKE 'B%' or m.name LIKE '9%')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
... WHERE `name` LIKE 'B%' OR `name` LIKE '9%'
```